# If else statements with sum of range of values from HTML

Tags: php, html, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have this HTML page wherein there are checkboxes with different numerical values and I've set up a PHP file to compute the sum of checked checkboxes (HTML then when the user clicks the submit button, the page will be redirected to the PHP file). What I'm trying to do is, based on the sum, can I use if else statements where I'll set a range of possible sums (i.e. 1-100, 101-500) and the ranges will have a correspnding values again. (The concept behind is, I'm doing this carbon footprint thing, and for 5k-10kg consumption of CO2, the equivalent number of earths needed to sustain your living is 2.50.)

HTML

```
<form action="index.php" method="post"/>
<h3>Laundry</h3>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" id="laundry1" class="sum" value="46" data-toggle="checkbox">Fabric Conditioner Pure 2L</label><br>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" id="laundry2" class="sum" value="44" data-toggle="checkbox">Fabric Conditioner Blue 4L</label><br>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" id="laundry3" class="sum" value="650" data-toggle="checkbox">Laundry Liquid 1.5L</label><br>
```

PHP (to sum the checked checkboxes)

```
<?php
if($_POST){
    $val = 0;
    foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $checkbox){
        $val += $checkbox;
    }
    echo $val;
}
?>
```

What I'm trying so far for the ifelse statements

```
<?php
if ($val >= 1 && $val <= 100) {
  echo "0.02";
  }

if else ($val >= 101 && $val <= 500) {
  echo "0.10";
  }
?>
```

I'm currenty stucked right now and any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You mean `else if`, not `if else` in last snippet, right? What is problem? It doesn't work or work incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

You `if else` is not the right syntax. Try this :

```
if ($val >= 1 && $val <= 100) {
  echo "0.02";
}
elseif ($val >= 101 && $val <= 500) {
  echo "0.10";
}
```

Use [`elseif`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php) or `else if` instead of `if else`.

Another not : use `isset()` to check if `$_POST` is defined :

```
if (isset($POST)) {
//...
}
```

Comment: Tried it sir but the output is sort of wrong. It still adds the checked checkbox but the equivalent becomes a combination numbers (for ex: the sum is 161, and the range equivalent is 0.10, it becomes 1610.10)

Comment: @ckdirecto You are `echo`ing the result. Where are you computing  the range?

Comment: @ckdirecto Are you `echo $val` somewhere before the `if`?

Answer (score 0):

Use `elseif` instead of many `if` so

```
<?php
if ($val >= 1 && $val <= 100) {
  echo "0.02";
}
elseif($val >= 101 && $val <= 500) {
  echo "0.10";
}
?>
```